# Oracle does not display the name of the integrity constraint violated

Tags: oracle

My system runs on IIS 7 and Oracle 12 for Windows x64.

When inserting a record into any table, if an integrity constraint is violated, it does not show me what is the table and what is the name of the constraint.

The message that appears is:

> ORA-02291 integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated parent key not found.

With Oracle 11 it worked correctly. There was no change in the system. In Oracle 19 also the same problem occurs.

Thank you.

Comment: I have seen similar errors with "%s", and missing the details.  Looks like a bug, where they are using a "printf" style formatting.  Oracle errors pretty much suck.

Comment: well; using this in exception block will give you finer details
dbms_utility.format_error_stack & dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace.

Comment: Probably best to contact support and have a bug filed as necessary

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
I forgot to comment that the system is developed in VB.NET. The connection to Oracle is done with Enterprise Library.